# Nsubstitute executing Action as parameter on a mocked interface

Tags: c#, mocking, action, nsubstitute

Is there anyway I can execute an action as a parameter from a mocked out service?

I have an interface that is used in the method I am unit testing:

```
interface IMyTracker
{
    void TrackerMethod(string name, Action action);
}
```

This is the method I want to unit test:

```
private void Method1(IMyTracker myTracker)
{

    myTracker.TrackerMethod("Method1",() =>
    {       
        // This is stuff I want to execute!
    }
}
```

Here is my unit test

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var trackerSub = Substitute.For<IMyTracker>();
    trackerSub.TrackerMethod(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Invoke<Action>()); //How do I execute the logic inside the lambda expression action? Is it at all possible? Or once it's mocked, is that logic lost?
    GetClassInstance().Method1(trackerSub);
}
```

Any help here would be great.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. It does not tell us what is actually happening as apposed to what was expected.

Comment: The `Arg.Invoke<Action>()` should cause the lambda to be invoked when `TrackerMethod` is called. There are some [examples like this in the docs](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/actions-with-arguments/). Do you have an example where this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

i created example code which show you how it works.
So at the start we get you interface:

```
public interface ITracker
{
    void TrackerMethod(string name, Action action);
}
```

Next we got the sample class which use this interface and do any action in the tracker, look here:

```
public class AnyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _anyLogger;

    public AnyClass(ILogger anyLogger)
    {
        this._anyLogger = anyLogger;
    }

    public void AnyMethod(ITracker tracker)
    {
        tracker.TrackerMethod("mymethod", () =>
        {
            _anyLogger.LogError("i was here");
        });
    }
}
```

and the unit test for this scenario can look like:

```
[Fact]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger>();
    var tracker = Substitute.For<ITracker>();
    tracker.TrackerMethod(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Invoke());
    AnyClass anyClass = new AnyClass(logger);
        
    anyClass.AnyMethod(tracker);
        
    logger.Received().LogError("i was here");
 }
```